# Grid produces too many hibernate queries - FetchMode.JOIN doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql, hibernate-mapping

I'm developing a webapp using Spring MVC and Hibernate. Thing is, that I need to show all my customer's clients, and each client has another entity associated ("Cobrador", I don't know the english translation here, sorry), I'm using JQgrid for such goal. When I execute the grid, I see in the log:

```
Hibernate: select cliente0_.id as id1_0_, cliente0_.activo as activo2_0_, cliente0_.apellido as apellido3_0_, cliente0_.cobrador as cobrador8_0_, cliente0_.dni as dni4_0_, cliente0_.email as email5_0_, cliente0_.nombre as nombre6_0_, cliente0_.telefono as telefono7_0_ from clientes cliente0_ where cliente0_.activo=1
Hibernate: select cobrador0_.id as id1_1_0_, cobrador0_.activo as activo2_1_0_, cobrador0_.apellido as apellido3_1_0_, cobrador0_.dni as dni4_1_0_, cobrador0_.email as email5_1_0_, cobrador0_.nombre as nombre6_1_0_, cobrador0_.telefono as telefono7_1_0_ from cobradores cobrador0_ where cobrador0_.id=?
Hibernate: select cobrador0_.id as id1_1_0_, cobrador0_.activo as activo2_1_0_, cobrador0_.apellido as apellido3_1_0_, cobrador0_.dni as dni4_1_0_, cobrador0_.email as email5_1_0_, cobrador0_.nombre as nombre6_1_0_, cobrador0_.telefono as telefono7_1_0_ from cobradores cobrador0_ where cobrador0_.id=?
Hibernate: select cobrador0_.id as id1_1_0_, cobrador0_.activo as activo2_1_0_, cobrador0_.apellido as apellido3_1_0_, cobrador0_.dni as dni4_1_0_, cobrador0_.email as email5_1_0_, cobrador0_.nombre as nombre6_1_0_, cobrador0_.telefono as telefono7_1_0_ from cobradores cobrador0_ where cobrador0_.id=?
```

Basically getting the clients, and then, for each client go gets the associated "cobrador". My Client entity is configured as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
public class Cliente {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;    
private String apellido;
private String nombre;
private int dni;
private String telefono;
private String email;
private boolean activo;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cobrador")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Cobrador cobrador;

//Contructors, getters and setters
}
```

BTW: The final hibernate execution is:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<T> getAllFiltering(String filter) { 
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + type.getSimpleName() + " " + filter);
    return q.list();
}
```

Where  is  and filter is " where activo=true".

Is there anyway to configure this relationship in order to execute only 1 query when loading the grid?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is not very convenient but `Hibernate` will not use the fetch strategy if you are using an `HQL` query (I.E using the createQuery method). If you want to make it work, you must use the `Criteria` API or specify the join in the HQL query.

In your case the query might be something like this :

```
from Cliente c left join fetch c.cobrador
```

From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) :

> The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:
>
> - retrieval via get() or load()
> - retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
> - Criteria queries
> - HQL queries if subselect fetching is used

As you can see, the fetch strategy defined doesn't affect HQL queries
if JOIN is the fetchMode.

Comment: Criterias worked like a charm. I didn't know them, thanks a lot!